# Stored procedure expects parameter that was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a `SqlDataSource` connected to a GridView and I am trying to get the edit working correctly, but with everything I try I still get that parameters are not supplied.

I have tried naming the parameters with and without the '@', it seems to make no difference. As you can see in the below image, the update parameters exist and even have values!

Example image:

[image: Image of error]

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="JobGV" DataSourceID="JobApprovalsDS" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
     OnRowCommand="JobGV_OnRowCommand" OnRowUpdating="JobGV_OnRowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Function" DataField="FunDesc" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Employee" DataField="EmpName" ReadOnly="true"/>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlEmps" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("appEmpID")%>' DataSourceID="EmpDS" DataTextField="EmpName" DataValueField="EmpID" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="data" Text='<%# Eval("appBusinessUnit") +";" + Eval("appFunctID") %>' Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("EmpName") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="JobApprovalsDS" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobClose %>" 
     SelectCommand="up_JobApprovalsSelect" 
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     UpdateCommand="up_JobApprovalsUpdate">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ShowAll" DefaultValue="1" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="AllPhases" DefaultValue="1" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="BusinessUnit" ControlID="ddlEditJob" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="@BusinessUnit" Type="String"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="@FunctID" Type="Int32"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="@EmpID" Type="Int32"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="@UpdateDate" Type="DateTime"/>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#:

```
protected void JobGV_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("Update"))
            {
                int empid = 0;
                string[] data;
                int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                GridViewRow row = JobGV.Rows[index];
                DropDownList ddlemp = (DropDownList) row.FindControl("ddlEmps");
                empid = int.Parse(ddlemp.SelectedValue);
                Label lbl = (Label) row.FindControl("data");
                data = lbl.Text.Split(';');

                JobApprovalsDS.UpdateParameters["@BusinessUnit"].DefaultValue = data[0];
                JobApprovalsDS.UpdateParameters["@FunctID"].DefaultValue = data[1];
                JobApprovalsDS.UpdateParameters["@EmpID"].DefaultValue = empid.ToString();
                //JobApprovalsDS.UpdateParameters.Add("BusinessUnit", data[0]);
                //JobApprovalsDS.UpdateParameters.Add("FunctID", data[1]);
                //JobApprovalsDS.UpdateParameters.Add("EmpID", empid.ToString());
            }
}

protected void JobGV_OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    JobApprovalsDS.Update();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the **update** process??

Well, in your `SqlDataSource`, you're **not** specifying that the `UpdateCommand` is talking to a stored procedure... you need to specify the `UpdateCommandType`,  too! (not just the `SelectCommandType`)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="JobApprovalsDS" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobClose %>" 
     SelectCommand="up_JobApprovalsSelect" 
     SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
     UpdateCommand="up_JobApprovalsUpdate"
     UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" >   **** this is missing from your code!
```

Comment: Thanks!  I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @Herrozerro: sometimes you just don't see the forest for the trees anymore, after searching for too long :-) A fresh pair of eyeballs helps :-)